# Vert-Align image and text in same TD in Outlook

Tags: css, outlook, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertical-align an image and a text-element (span) within the same TD.

Heres my code:

```
<table bgcolor="#ff0000" style="background-color: #ff0000;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" height="20" style="height: 20px; padding: 5px; vertical-align: middle;">
            <a href="#">
                <img height="20" width="25" style="display: inline; height: 20px; width: 25px; vertical-align: middle;" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files.crsend.com/181000/181395/images/cart.png"/>

                <!--#text_line #-->
                <span style="vertical-align: middle; color: #fff;">&nbsp;10,95€</span>
                <!--#/text_line#-->
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

[Example-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtRHx.png)

I cannot seperate the img-element and the text-element into seperate TD's, because it has to be a single anchor-element wrapping both the image and the text. I cannot wrap the TD's with an anchor-element since it is not HTML-valid and won't work in outlook.

Any Suggestions?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Set your table `border-collapse` to collapse, your td `padding` to 0 and your anchor `display` to block. In this way, the anchor element will fit completely your td without useless margins. Then just set `vertical-align` to middle for both img and anchor element to align them on the same line.

```html
<table style="background-color: #ff0000; border-collapse: collapse;">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <a href="#" style="display: block; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding: 5px;">
        <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files.crsend.com/181000/181395/images/cart.png" style="height: 20px; width: 25px; vertical-align: middle;" />
        <!--#text_line #-->
        <span style="vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;10,95€</span>
        <!--#/text_line#-->
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```